# Mathematica fill colour

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[image]

I have created this using the mathematica bezier curves. I just want to know how could I fill these fonts with colour using some mathematica routines.

Thanks

Comment: May be of use: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8291

Comment: It would be helpful in providing a solution if you posted some code for your Bezier curves.

Comment: Another promising link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5821/363

Answer (score 1):

If you look at all the examples hidden behind the drop down links on

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilledCurve.html

this shows a number of examples of closed bezier curves filled with colors.

Comment: Is there any algorithm like flood fill

Comment: Mathematica sometimes, perhaps often, uses different names for functions. Looking at [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/alphaindex/Fla.html) there are two entries under floodfill and neither of those look like what you are looking for. If you Google for Mathematica floodfill then you find a few hits that might give you the answer I think you want to get.